# How can I make 2sxc app URLs show up in DNN's Sitemap.aspx?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc app (using C# Razor template) that shows a listing and details view. I have 10 items. Each item has a friendly URL. Looks something like this:

```
domain.com/landing-page/details/the-benefits-of-jargon
domain.com/landing-page/details/code-samples
domain.com/landing-page/details/highlights-and-use-cases
etc…
```

Is there a way that I can make these URLs appear in the DNN Sitemap.aspx ? (as it stands, the only page that appears is “landing-page” because that’s the only real DNN page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two ways. Dnn has some way you can write code to extend the page-structure provider. IMHO this is super difficult to do, but probably the official architected way.

Our way is much simpler ;)

1. Create a WebAPI which creates a standalone sitemap for your needs. You could assemble some strings, but we recommend to use the C# Xml object just to be sure. You can find some brand-new example on the RSS feed of the latest Blog5 app.
2. Register this endpoint as another sitemap on Google (yes, you can do that :)

That's how we do it - and we've been very successful with it creating landing-page systems that generate hundreds, sometimes thousands of unique landing pages.

Comment: Can't you just list the additional sitemap(s) in the robots.txt file and not worry about registering them? To be honest, I haven't tried it, but I believe I've both read about it and seen others doing it this way. I love the idea of using the C# Xml object to do this, thanks for the ideas!!

Comment: TBH I don't know. The specs say it works, so it probably does, but best try and tell us all if it worked ;)

Comment: Also note that in many cases, the robots.txt may be replaced (maybe with an update), so it could be safer to add it to the google admin.